# Why is macro declared this way?

Tags: c++, c, macros, c-preprocessor, errno

What is the reason to define macro this way:

```
#define test_errno(msg) do{if (errno) {perror(msg); exit(EXIT_FAILURE);}} while(0)
```

I mean what is the reason behind `do{}while(0)`? Of course it will be done once only, zero is constant, cannot change to nonzero somehow, so why to use such construction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It allows things like

```
if (condition) 
   test_errno(...);
```

to work properly with or without braces.

Comment: a missing `;`. the macro considers this and it needs an ending `;`, so it looks like a real function.

Answer (score 2):

There is no good reason in this case.  In similar constructs, it is useful for the statements inside to have `continue` and `break` to do useful things.

```
#define test_errno(msg) do {if (cond1) break;   \
                            if (cond2) break;   \
                            if (cond3) break;   \
               do_something_if_all_condtions_met();} while(0)
```